# Clone all magento products

Tags: products, magento-1.9.2.0

Is there a way, to clone all products ?

I would like to create new SKU in the process and disable all cloned products for one store view.

I am willing to do this with PHP or MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magmi to handle mass data import or output in Magento.

Here is the wiki link  of Magmi: [Magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=What_is_magmi)